# SetLocaleInfo fails

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have function

```
procedure bgGetKeyboardLayoutList(List: TStrings);
var
  AList : array [0..50] of Hkl;
  AklName: array [0..255] of Char;
  i: Longint;
begin
  List.Clear;
  for i := 0 to GetKeyboardLayoutList(SizeOf(AList), AList) - 1 do
    begin
      GetLocaleInfo(LoWord(AList[i]), LOCALE_SLANGUAGE, AklName, SizeOf(
               AklName));
      List.AddObject(AklName, Pointer(AList[i]));
    end;
end;
```

The function is called

```
procedure TDefaultInputMethod.Scan;
begin
  bgGetKeyboardLayoutList(FSL);
end;
```

But when I try in opposite direction to use SetLocaleInfo, I have no success
code:

```
procedure TDefaultInputMethod.SetAsDefault(index: integer);
begin
  ActivateKeyboardLayout(Hkl(FSL.Objects[index]), 0); //this line works
  if SetLocaleInfo(LoWord(FSL.Objects[index]), LOCALE_SLANGUAGE, PChar(FSL[index]))  then
     ShowMessage('Uspeh')
  else
    begin
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetLastError));
    end;
end;
```

GetLasrError returns 1004

Thanks in advance
Bojan

Comment: What does `ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));` tell you?

Comment: It'll probably say something like "You can't use LOCALE_SLANGUAGE on Windows 7 or later" :)

Comment: ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) - Invalid flags

Comment: See the docs. LOCALE_SLANGUAGE is not one of the information types you can set.

Comment: But in GetLocaleinfo with LOCALE_SLANGUAGE gives correct answer.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: You must have posted your comment while I was researching my answer. If you want to post one with that info, I'll delete mine - you were here first with the comment.

Comment: @Ken, your answer is fine, you've got my vote. :) And my comment has a vote too. :)

Comment: We don't know what parameters you are passing to SetLocalInfo. The very basics of asking a question are that you must make it 100% clear what you are asking. As it stands, we have to guess as to what these parameters are. Simply present a single short complete compilable program.

Comment: @Bojan I think Ken's answer is accurate. On a side note I would say that your code has a **lot** of errors: 1. Incorrect use of `SizeOf()` instead of `Length()` 2. Missing error checking on `GetLocaleInfo` and `ActivateKeyboardLayout` 3. `List.AddObject` passes the same pointer to stack memory each time you call it

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Incorrect use of SizeOf(): We are speaking about array. List.AddObject passes the same pointer.... - No, it always passes new pointer to HKL, In GetLocaleInfo, yes you are right is not error missing, but error is not here.

Comment: No. Must be Length() rather than SizeOf(). Read the docs to learn why. You are right about the pointer. Different every time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ActivateKeyboardLayout(Hkl(FSL.Objects[index]), 0); exists but it sets only for the current thread, and it works fine. Error is SetLocaleInfo(LoWord(FSL.Objects[index]), LOCALE_SLANGUAGE, PChar(FSL[index])), First parameter I changed in all combination, but Ken and Sertac are right - LOCALE_SLANGUAGE can't be used in SetLocaleInfo.

Comment: I was trying to correct all your other errors. You did not check return value for ActivateKeyboardLayout. That's an error. And Ken's answer is accurate.

Answer (score 5):

`ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));` indicates that `1004` is `Invalid flags`.

According to the [`SetLocaleInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation at MSDN, this corresponds to `ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS`, and that's caused by an invalid value being passed to the function.

The problem is with the second parameter (`LOCALE_SLANGUAGE`), which according to the [documentation again](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not one of the values that can be used with `SetLocaleInfo`. It can only be used with `GetLocaleInfo` to retrieve information. (See the section starting with the heading `Constants Used in the LCType Parameter of GetLocaleInfo, GetLocaleInfoEx, and SetLocaleInfo` on that page.)

Comment: I have used all of them: LOCALE_INVARIANT, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT and LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT. Result always was False with same 1004 error.

Comment: Read the section I mentioned in the last paragraph - it **specifically** lists the flags that can be used with `SetLocaleInfo`.

Comment: Does that means that can't change language for all system, just for current thread?

Comment: Read the documentation: "This function writes to the registry, where it sets values that are associated with a **particular user instead of a particular application**. These registry values **affect the behavior of other applications** run by the user. As a rule, an application should call this function only when the user has explicitly requested the changes. **The registry settings should not be changed for the convenience of a single application.**"

Comment: @bojan - I'm not sure if it's what you want but see SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG of SystemParametersInfo.

Comment: @Sertac: I'm confused here, too. The question asked why `SetLocaleInfo` was failing with error 1004, but the comments seem to be mutating into something else instead. bojan should ask a new question if there's something else needed; this question has been answered. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how, but I marked it as answered. I was so tired and nervous. This morning I have tested this function and on Win XP. Result is same.

Comment: Please read the documentation at the **first** link I posted to MSDN. At the bottom of the page, it very clearly says: **Minimum supported client Windows 2000 Professional [desktop apps only]**

Comment: @KenWhite Where does Win2000 come into this question?

Comment: @David: The comment above mine. "I have tested this function and on WinXP result is the same". I cited the docs that said when the function became available. Why is that an issue?

Comment: @Ken Bojan is probably responding to  500 - Internal Server Error's comment to the Q. Since Bojan managed to call the function on XP he already knows that it exists there.

Comment: @David: I took it as addressed to me, because bojan referenced the accept to my answer which was then reversed this morning. I don't see where it matters, though; if it was addressed to someone specific, it should have been indicated as such, and it's also quite common to respond to things not addressed to you anyway (as you did here now, for instance). :-)

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of confusion here. I really do wish that people could supply complete code. In this question it takes no effort at all to do so! I see what you mean about the documentation for `LOCALE_SLANGUAGE`, but you can't use that for `GetLocaleInfo` either according to the docs.

Comment: @David: I agree. In fact, `LOCALE_SLANGUAGE` is [deprecated as of WIn7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in favor of `LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDLANGUAGENAME`. I don't understand the reversal of the accept here; I answered the question about what error 1004 meant and why it was happening. bojen seems to have gone somewhere else with expectations, though, instead of asking whatever the real question might be.